This/next day of the week
If it's Sunday, which of "this Wednesday" or "next Wednesday" refers to the Wednesday next week?
I think that on a Sunday, "this Wednesday" refers to the current week and "next Wednesday" refers to the next week.

This question is similar to: Which day does "next Tuesday" refer to?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. // But see also J Lawler's reference to Fillmore's lectures on deixis at What does 'next Monday' mean?.

See also Meaning of 'last / this / next Monday'.

Sunday is traditionally the first day of the week, so what do you consider 'the current week'? (I would say 'on Wednesday' or 'this Wednesday' to refer to the upcoming one.)

As a native speaker, having spoken British English for over seventy years, if today  is Monday then 'this Friday' happens in four day's time and 'next Friday' means in eleven day's time. Unfortunately, one is never certain if one is talking to a native speaker or not so one guards one's words to avoid ambiguity. 'Next Friday, that's the fifteenth, OK ?' (Eyebrows raised, head nodding, ensuring agreement.) Up-voted +1.

To be clear, if it is this week I would say "on Wednesday", and if it is the following week I would say "Wednesday week".

@RichieBendall Although this page has been Closed, I suggest manually incorporating my suggested edit, which clarifies your intent and pre-empts Kate Bunting's above comment, but which has been rejected.

To me:

"this Friday" and "the next Friday" both mean the upcoming Friday (never the preceding one);
if today is Monday, then "next Friday" means the second upcoming Friday;
if today is Sunday, I wouldn't say "next Friday", as there'd be too much ambiguity (just like I wouldn't say "it's due on Friday" to indicate that something is due tomorrow).

I'm posting this answer—which disagrees with both your suggestions—to illustrate that there is apparently no universal consensus regarding what "this/next day-of-the-week" means.
N.B. In the above usage, "next Friday" is not synonymous with "the next Friday".
